Const-correctness of std::reference_wrapper
A const std::reference_wrapper works similar to a reference, or a T* const (demo):
#include <functional>

struct S {
    void operator()() { i++; }
    int i = 0;
};

int main() {
    S s;
    const std::reference_wrapper<S> r = s;
    // now s.i == 0
    r();
    // now s.i == 1

    S* const p = &s;
    // now s.i == 1
    (*p)();
    // now s.i == 2
}

r is const, and std::reference_wrapper::operator() is a const method, thus we can call it, which in turn modifies the pointee. But, this operator() is a standard library function, thus [res.on.data.races]#3 quoted from the C++23 standard applies to it:

A C++ standard library function shall not directly or indirectly modify objects ([intro.multithread]) accessible by threads other than the current thread unless the objects are accessed directly or indirectly via the function's non-const arguments, including this.

Does std::reference_wrapper violate this rule?

This reasoning also applies to int i = 0; const auto f = [&]{ ++i; }; std::invoke(f);

This cannot possibly apply to indirect modifications via a user-supplied callback.

I think for this one you can probably argue that the "unless otherwise specified" in p1 applies.

@T.C.: Link to p1: [res.on.data.races]#1. As I see [refwrap] doesn't specify an exception to the rule.

It specifies it to make that call, so it makes that call. If that call happens to break the rule, then it specified an exception to the rule.

@T.C.: It's more logical the other way around. If that call happens to break the rule, then it broke the rule. By what means does one choose between your and my interpretation?

Problem is that std::reference_wrapper<S> does not store a value, but reference. std::reference_wrapper<S> is not changed, but S s; is changed.
It is like holding a constant pointer to modifiable object.
So everything is ok. r remains unchanged. s is updated.
So const version of function call operator is called and this member function call function call operator on s which is not const.
Documentation clearly states that operator() for is const
template< class... ArgTypes >
std::invoke_result_t<T&, ArgTypes...>
    operator() ( ArgTypes&&... args ) const noexcept(/* see below */);


There is nothing new in this answer, and it doesn't answer the question. I didn't fully understand the last two sentences. Check your typos.
